# Interrelated resources

Tags: python-2.7, simpy, traffic-simulation

I am modelling a train station(using simpy, with python 2.7) where there are some incoming routes, some outgoing routes and some platforms. Now, when one of these resources is occupied, I can't assign a train to certain other resources.

Now when a train engages a route - i.e. traverses it - some other routes in the stations area become unusable for some time. If I were to model a route as a resource, then a request yielded at that resource will affect/engage other resources as well.

Is there some way of modelling resources, such that engagement of one resource_A puts resource_B, resource_C out of action for some predetermined amount of time?

Aseem Awad

Comment: Let me clarify this a little bit more. You have a set of resources. The event of a train engaging a resource means that the resource will be occupied for the traversal_time of the train. Now while yielding the request for that resource we need to check whether other resources are engaged or not.

Comment: Thanks, Aseem. Instead of signing your post, you can change your display name from user14916 to be your name or your nickname.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just request the other resources (B and C; maybe using preemption) once you get resource A and release all three resources once you are done with A.

Comment: Thank you. Nice to get a response from Stefan himself!
The preemption option doesn't really work for me as when a resource is being used, i.e. a train is traversing a track-section, preemption doesn't make sense.