# Nested Lists and their index calls

Tags: python

I was wondering how I would go about assigning a value to a specific index in a list that is inside another list. For example:

For a list parentList

```
for i in range(0,rows, 1):
        parentList[i] = []
        for j in range(0,cols,1):
            parentList[i[j]] = 0
```

Not sure if that is even the right syntax for assignment like this.

I know I can do .append, but what I need to do for my problem is create a sparse matrix, so everything should be 0 except for the values that the user specifies in the form
`(row) (col) (value)`.

So I thought using the indexes of the lists would help with assignment. If there is a better way, please let me know!

EDIT: This is an example of what is being done

input:

```
1 2 2

1 3 3

2 1 4

3 3 5

0 0 0


1 3 7

2 2 8

3 2 9

3 3 6

0 0 0
```

The first matrix in the input is:

```
0 2 3

4 0 0

0 0 5
```

The second matrix is:

```
0 0 7

0 8 0

0 9 6
```

Their product is:

```
0 43 18

0 0 28

0 45 30
```

So the output should be:

```
1 2 43

1 3 18

2 3 28

3 2 45

3 3 30

0 0 0
```

I have to use a 1D array of linked lists to represent this in my code and all input and output is done through the Python Shell.

Comment: Use a `dict` with a `tuple` (row, col) is probably the simplest way to emulate a sparse matrix using only Python builtins

Comment: I don't follow. Could you show an example input and the corresponding desired output?

Comment: `range(0,rows,1)` is equivalent to `range(rows)`. Starting at 0 and incrementing by 1 are the defaults, so you don't need them.

Comment: Not sure why, but the instructor specified this: "Your program should represent the sparse matrix as a one-dimensional array of linked lists. "

Comment: @Udent It'll be a good idea to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553392/interrelated-resources) your post with that and any other requirements/guidance you've been given so others can help you better... (and not suggest ways that you're not allowed/expected to do it etc...)

Comment: One good way to manage a sparse matrix in Python is by using Scipy library: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html

Comment: Please specify in your post what the output should be. Is it supposed to be a m*m matrix (list of lists)?

Comment: Ok, put most of the stuff in that he was asking for, sorry just learning how to use this website, will be more thorough from the getgo in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to work with numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.empty((3,3))
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        a[i][j]=0
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: for this, are the values automatically converted to floating points?

Comment: You can set datatype of your choice as: **a=np.empty((3,3),dtype=int)**

Comment: This might seem like a dumb question, but when you specify what position of shape, that is just like which one of the 3's specified earlier correct? So for: 

a = np.empty((x,y))
x = a.shape[0]
y = a.shape[1]?

Answer (score 0):

Python lists aren't sparse - but there are other packages like numpy and scipy that provide them. If your dataset isn't that big and you are okay just prefilling a list, this will do it:

```
rows = 100
cols = 13
l = [[0]*cols for _ in rows]
```

The `[0]*cols` creates an inner list filled with zeros, and `[[0]*cols for _ in rows]` repeats that operation for the number of rows you want.

After that, you address individual cells like

```
l[2][3] = 111
```